# How do I check if a button exists in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm scraping reviews from a website and would like to extract the title, review text and language. I'm determining the language through a *Translate* button. If the review is in English, the button is not displayed and therefore skipped by Scrapy.

I'd like to add a condition to my code that adds "en" to the list if the button doesn't exist. At the moment Scrapy just returns the other 4 languages although I have 5 reviews.

Expected result: `["de", "en", "de", "es", "fr"]`
Current result: `["de", "de", "es", "fr"]`

```
import scrapy

class EccoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "ecco_button"

    # Gets a specific product
    start_urls = ["https://www.ecco-verde.co.uk/reviews/acorelle/eau-de-parfum-land-of-cedar?&rating_page=1&lang=all"]

    def parse(self, response):

        title= response.xpath('//div[@class="comment-box"]//h3/text()').getall()

        # If the language is English a translate button doesn't exist and "en" has to be added manually
        language = None
        # This is a very Selenium-like approach where I'm searching for a button within //p[@class="comment"]. Selenium throws an error when it can't find the button, but Scrapy returns either the first or all instances.
        for translate in response.xpath('//p[@class="comment"]'):
            button = response.xpath('.//button/@data-review-lang').get()
        print(button)

        yield{"Title": title, "Language": language}
```

Comment: Did you mean to put `translate` instead of `response` within the loop?

Comment: Oh lol. I didn't even notice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add "en" to a list if it doesn't exist

```
if "en" not in button:
    button.append("en")
```

If you're trying to scrape reviews and categorize them by language, you can figure out what languages are available from the `//*[@id="js-reviewLang"]` selector, then make a request for each language:

```
https://www.ecco-verde.co.uk/reviews/acorelle/eau-de-parfum-land-of-cedar?&rating_page=1&lang=en
https://www.ecco-verde.co.uk/reviews/acorelle/eau-de-parfum-land-of-cedar?&rating_page=1&lang=fr
https://www.ecco-verde.co.uk/reviews/acorelle/eau-de-parfum-land-of-cedar?&rating_page=1&lang=es
...
```

Comment: Wouldn't that add 'en' to the end of the list though rather than at a specific position where I need it? I wanted to avoid calling every single language separately since I'm scraping a lot of websites and I already had to implement complex pagination logic. But maybe that's the only possible solution.